# Calling webservice and getting JSON response in Javascript without using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

I need to call a web service from Javascript of a html page whose response will be in JSON. Can someone suggest me the best way to do this?

I have seen that XMLHTTPRequest can be used to do this. But I cannot use it due to same domain origin policy. My web service resides on an external server.

NOTE: I do not want to use jQuery or any such frameworks. Need to be done in plain Javascript only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using jsonp? http://json-p.org/